# Unexpected behavior with closures: callback holds the last value

Tags: javascript, closures, bind

I'll get to the point: I have this loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= toSchedule; i++) {
        when = trackWrapper.lastPlay +
                (trackDuration +
                (looper.timeInterval - trackDuration));

        track.play(true, when);
        trackWrapper.lastPlay = when;
    }
```

The `play` method has this inside the body:

```
[...]
// Here when is a different value for each call (verified)
// Many calls of the play method are performed before the returned function below is run as a callback
        function playingCallback(myWhen){

            return function(buffers){
                // Here myWhen will always be equal to the value of the last call occurred BEFORE the first callback execution
                console.log("myWhen = "+myWhen);
                [...]

            };
        };

        var realCallback = playingCallback(when);

        track.scheduled.push(when);
        track.recorder.getBuffer(realCallback);
```

So, for example:

```
play(true, 1);
play(true, 2);
play(true, 3);

// Wait for it...

myWhen = 3;
myWhen = 3;
myWhen = 3;
```

Now: I've read about closures, I've read about the "infamous loop problem", I've read tens of answers here on StackOverflow but I couldn't figure this out. It's the second time I have this kind of problem with callbacks so, at this point, I guess I haven't completely understood what is going on.

Could you please explain to me what is supposed to be wrong with the code above? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please be a bit clearer about `play()`'s definition? Show what its arguments are called, etc...

Comment: You need to use the argument of `play`, not the `when` variable from the loop.

Comment: The problem is ... that's NOT the way to control a player. Trying to control it with a stack of predicted start times is doomed to failure. Say, for example, the user pauses a track for 10 seconds. Ask yourself, are the start times of any later tracks still valid? To form a track-list, you need to push TRACKS, not times, onto a stack. Then you need code that services the stack whenever the player becomes free.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should understand the following rule: A clousure will have access to its "surrounding scope", even after the scope has been exited. But it will be the state of the scope at execution time and not(!) at creation time of the closure

If you create a closure inside a loop, it will have access to the loop variable. But the loop will most likely already have ended. So the loop variable will hold the value of its last loop.

So if your closure is a callback you should create a copy of your relevant scope variable(s) at creation time and use this copy at execution time. You can do this (for example) by creating an inner closure from an immediately executing anonymous function

```
function myOuterScope(count) {
   for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
      setTimeout((function(local_i) {
         // this function will be immediately executed. local_i is a copy of i at creation time
         return function() {
            // this is the function that will be called as a callback to setTimeout
            // use local_i here, and it will be 0, 1, 2 instead of 3, 3, 3
         }
      })(i)
      , 1000);
   }
}
myOuterScope(3);
```